# Are there any $x,y,z$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for which the following equations hold?

Tags: absolute-value

> Are there any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the following equations hold?
>   $$|x+1| \leq 2\\ |y+1| \leq 3\\ |y-z| \leq 1$$

With the given we know that $x$ is between $[-3,1]$, $y$ is between $[-4,2]$, and $(y-z)$ is between $[-1,1]$.

Using a triangle inequality:

$$|(x+1)+(-y-1)|= |x-y| \leq |x+1| + |y+1|$$

there i can see that |x-y| can be maximum 7; and on the right side |x+1| can me maximum 2; and |y+1| maximum 3; which is a contradiction since 7 is never less than 5.

maybe this is proven but am not sure
The anwser to this question is no.

any feedback is welcome
Thanks.

Comment: The answer is yes. Let $x=y=z=-1$.

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: Yes From class. and the answer was given, but no explaination

Comment: It seems to me that you can forget about the first condition. Namely, $|x+1|\leq 2.$ This is trivially satisfiable, and since $x$ does not feature in any of the other equations, you can simply forget about it.

Comment: I suspect some conditions are lacking.

Comment: That is all that was given. i was told it could be shown with the triangle innequality used above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every
$$x \in [-3,1]$$
and 
$$y \in [-4,2]$$
it is possible to select some $z$:
$$z \in [y-1,y+1]$$

Comment: This points out that the choice of $x \in [-3,1]$ does not restrict the further choices of $y,z$, and that indeed $z$ can easily be chosen based only on a prior choice for $y \in [-4,2]$.